# Get position of first line of text in multi-line select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop some code that positions a tooltip above the selected text. It works pretty well if the selection is only 1 line, but as soon as I select multiple lines the left position I am getting is the far left of the text block (because the 2nd line goes all the way to the left).

[image: Correct Image]

[image: Incorrect Image]

I get the position using:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
//$this is the div containing the text
containerRect = $this[0].getBoundingClientRect()
selectionRect = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();

$tooltip.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: selectionRect.top - containerRect.top - 45,
    left: selectionRect.left - containerRect.left,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
```

I am not sure if it is possible to get the left position of the top line in this situation.

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JDfrfDOdR4Gh1Ztrlo0Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `event.pageX` to get the cursors position and trigger it on `mousedown`. You probably have to readjust your code a bit, but it should do the trick.

```
var getMousePosition = function(){
    mousePosition = event.pageX;
}
$this.on('mousedown', getMousePosition);
```

edited **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xusfzsneTCf6j5CMcpje?p=preview)**

Note: This works when text is marked from top to bottom. For it to work in both ways you have to get the position again on `mouseup` (when `event.pageY` is less the on mousedown)

working **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xusfzsneTCf6j5CMcpje?p=preview)** example for both ways.

Comment: Looks good and makes sense now that I think about it. Thank you